# Получить количество записей пользователей и отсортировать

Tags: inner-join, mysql

Здравствуйте.

Есть 2 таблицы:

- users(поля: id, uid, login, first_name, last_name)
- tasks_done(поля: id, author_id, section, url, read)

Как мне составить такой запрос на MySQL?

```
Получить количество всех записей каждого пользователя из tasks_done, соединить с таблицей users(чтобы отобразить имя и фамилию) и отсортировать users по полученному количеству из tasks_done.
```

Связываются поля: **uid** из таблицы `users` с **author_id** из таблицы `tasks_done`

Всё конечно было легче, если не получение количества из tasks_done и сортировка по нему, которая меня запутала.

Comment: Всё интересней задачки становяться )) Сейчас, кроме всего прочего, нам нужно еще и догадаться, а какое ж поле в таблице *tasks_done* связывает те самые записи, с пользователями в первой таблице ... и есть ли оно там вообще.

Comment: @Deonis, обновил пост, извиняюсь :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[На фиддле можно потестить](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/31188/1/0), а запрос, как я думаю, подойдет такой:

```
SELECT 
  `users`.`login`,
  `tasks_done`.`author_id`,
  COUNT(`tasks_done`.`id`) as `cnt`
FROM
  `tasks_done`
  INNER JOIN `users` ON (`tasks_done`.`author_id` = `users`.`uid`)
GROUP BY
  `tasks_done`.`author_id`
ORDER BY `cnt`
```

Сортировку **ASC/DESC** - по вашему усмотрению

Comment: @Deonis, Вы гений! Все работает на отлично!

Comment: @ModaL, ну ну )) Не надо так громко, а то я нацепляю себе медалей на грудь, забью на работу, нажрусь и пойду в Oracle ногой двери открывать ;)